# How to connect two svg elements using a line in raphaeljs

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I know there are some examples on SO already done but I want to understand how the actual internals work. I know how to create a line using M and L attributes but I want to understand how to connect shapes using javascript.

I went through some examples but I couldn't understand how its implemented. Any examples or links would be appreciated

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Editor</title>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/connector.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function ()
            {
                var paper = new Raphael(Raphael("container", "100%", "100%"));
                var sidebar = paper.rect(0, 43.5, 69, 620);
                var rect = paper.rect(10, 50, 51, 41, 5).attr({stroke: '#6DAACA', 'stroke-width': 1, fill: '#D6F2FC'});
                var circle1 = paper.circle(35, 145, 25).attr({fill: '#fff', 'stroke-width': 2, stroke: '#399324'});
                var circle2 = paper.circle(35, 225, 25).attr({fill: '#fff', 'stroke-width': 4, stroke: '#9E2F3C'});
                var circle3 = paper.circle(35, 310, 25).attr({fill: '#fff', 'stroke-width': 4, stroke: '#D5C096'});
                var Customrect = paper.path("M25 370 L10 370 L10 411 L25 411 L25 370 L61 370 L61 411 L25 411");

                // circle clonning
                paper.set(circle1);
                var clone_handler = function () {
                    var x = this.clone();
                    x.drag(move, start, up);
                };
                var start = function (x, y, event) {
                    this.ox = this.attr("cx");
                    this.oy = this.attr("cy");
                },
                        move = function (dx, dy) {
                            this.attr({
                                cx: this.ox + dx,
                                cy: this.oy + dy
                            });
                        },
                        up = function () {
                            this.animate({
                                r: 20,
                                opacity: .8
                            }, 500, ">");
                        };
                circle1.mousemove(clone_handler);
                circle2.mousemove(clone_handler);
                circle3.mousemove(clone_handler);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                <h1 id="title">Editor</h1>
                <div id="footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the live demo: https://jsbin.com/qawupugivi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Did you get the solution. If yes can you help me? As i also searching for the same. Thanks

Comment: @Zaheer it's not possible in Raphael Js. Go with any other svg lib. May be d3js

Comment: what about family tree? are you succeed?

Comment: Haven't tried that

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a line with either the line() method, or as a path(). You seem to want to know the path method, so will do that.

You need to think where the line will be drawn to, I'll do it by choosing the center of an object, so it should work with any shape.

We'll set up a handler, so select an object on dblclick()

```
x.dblclick( addLine )
```

Then a function to do the actual adding of the path.

First we get the two bounding boxes by Raphael, which provides the centre of an element (note, the native getBBox method only provides x,y,width,height, but Raph provides some extra bits).

Then we create the new path,

M = Move to
L = Line to

So we move M to the point we want to start drawing (centre of element 1), and then Line To L the centre of the other element.

Drag the elements out, then double click 2 elements to draw a line between them

```
function addLine() {
   if( lastEl ) {
      bb1 = this.getBBox();    
      bb2 = lastEl.getBBox();
      var newPath =   paper.path('M'+bb1.cx+','+bb1.cy+'L'+bb2.cx+','+bb2.cy);
      newPath.attr({ stroke: 'blue'})

   } 
   lastEl = this;
}
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/zinumagafa/1/edit?html,css,output) : double click 2 elements

You could also just use a line rather than a path, same principle.

You can hide the centre of the lines by insertBefore the elements, so that it appears 'on top'

If you drag the element after the line, it will not move, you will need to code that as part of your drag handler to update the path or line (which is what certain libraries do for you).

Comment: What is `lastEl` is in `if(lastEl)`?

Comment: And I guess `this` stands for current element right? and why there is zero in `this.getBox(0)`?

Comment: I modified code a little to achieve line draw on mouse drag but it isn't working. Please check https://jsbin.com/filohigimu/edit?html,output

Comment: There was a typo, the 0 wasn't supposed to be there (it wasn't on the jsbin). lastEl, is the last element selected. This stands for the object passed into the function (which in Raphs case will often be the element, but you need to see the docs for the specifics)..The jsbin you have has an error in the console.

Comment: instead of double click, How do I drag and draw line between shapes?

Comment: Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/9f4wM/ but in my case I don't have separate background to draw line. I need to use the same container

Comment: Thats a different question really that I would ask separately, make sure you are specific about 'how' it should work.

Comment: Already posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233474/draw-line-on-mouse-drag-in-raphael-js