# draw line on mouse drag in raphael js

Tags: svg, raphael

This is what I have tried:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Editor</title>
            <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9"/>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/connector.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style.css" />

            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function ()
        {
            var paper = new Raphael(Raphael("container", "100%", "100%"));
            var line = paper.path();
            var start = function (x, y) {
                this.ox = this.attr("x");
                this.oy = this.attr("y");
                var line = paper.path("M", this.ox, this.oy);
            },
                    move = function (dx, dy) {
                        this.attr({
                            x: this.ox + dx,
                            y: this.oy + dy
                        });
                       paper.path("L",x,y);
                    },
                    up = function () {
                        this.animate({
                            opacity: 0
                        }, 500);
                    };
                    paper.set(line).drag(move, start, up);
        };
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="header" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                    <h1 id="title">Editor</h1>
                    <div id="footer"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here's the live demo: https://jsbin.com/giqufilusu/1/edit?html,output

I don't know why its not working. Is there a syntax problem or I didn't code the correct way. There are some examples on web but most of them use jquery + raphael js to draw line on mouse events but I want to draw with `drag()` method of raphael. How do I fix this?

Comment: Not sure why you are calling 'line()', where is that from ?

Comment: What I want is this: http://jsfiddle.net/rRtAq/9358/  I tried this example with and without jquery with no luck.

Comment: Anyway I am going to try with paper js. Raphael isn't working out

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got you right.

I guess [this](https://jsbin.com/pajisejati/1/edit?html,output) is what you want to achieve?

You defined the `line` variable only in the scope of the start function. To adapt the line you need to make it available to all functions. The jsBin is a quick and dirty approach which should give you a hint how you can do this line drawing with Raphael.

Comment: Line should be drawn with out the help of circles

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: For now line draw when circle is moved(in jsbin) but I would like to have it drawn only when mouse is moved